# Adding a Mask modifier to any mesh is causing it to instantly disappear, no matter the settings

Tags: masking

[image: This is what it looks like when the modifier is disabled in realtime.]

[image: This is what it's like when I enable it on the sphere and add one to the cube.]

I tried this in Blender 4.0 and 3.4 and started new projects and the issue shows up in both. It didn't happen for a couple of spheres for some reason and it doesn't happen to duplicates when I duplicate the ones that didn't glitch out. I'm at a loss here and I haven't seen anyone posting about this exact issue. The sphere has multiple modifiers on it but the cube only has the mask modifier on it in my examples.

Answer (score 0):

By default the *Mask* modifier will mask the whole mesh except the selected group. If you haven't selected any group it will mask the whole mesh. You can invert the masked vertices with the *Invert* button though, so in your case just click on this button:

[image]